# Merge arrays and group to produce a count for each combined array value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4c6fb6993a721b3479a27e"),
    "score" : 8.3,
    "page" : "message",
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-01-03T06:49:19.232Z"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2018-01-03T05:52:54.446Z"),
    "slug" : [ 
        "@APPLE"
    ],
    "__v" : 0
},
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4c6fb6993a721b3479a27e"),
        "score" : 9.3,
        "page" : "@BANANA",
        "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-01-03T06:49:19.232Z"),
        "createdate" : ISODate("2018-01-03T05:52:54.446Z"),
        "slug" : [ 
            "@APPLE"
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4c6fb6993a721b3479a27e"),
        "score" : 5.3,
        "page" : "@BANANA",
        "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-01-03T06:49:19.232Z"),
        "createdate" : ISODate("2018-01-03T05:52:54.446Z"),
        "slug" : [ 
            "@BANANA"
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

Now I want to calculate the sum of score according to my Filter Like this:

```
@APPLE: 8.3+9.3 = 17.6 i.e @APPLE: 17.6,
@BANANA: 9.3+5.3 = 14.6 i.e @BANANA: 14.6
```

So for this I have to pick only last 1 hour data rather than picking the whole database
. So my query is like this

```
var newTime = new Date();
newTime.setHours( newTime.getHours() - 1 );
db.Test.find({"lastmodified":{$gt: newTime}})
```

so By this I can get only last 1 hour value. Now I am confuse that how i can do sum with filter. I also attached filter query i.e

```
db.Test.find({"lastmodified":{$gt: newTime}}, {$or: [{slug: {$in: ['@APPLE']}}, {page: '@APPLE'}]})
```

But it does not give anything. any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you using $or in the first place ? Does slug array always contain one value ? You need a aggregation query.

Comment: No. Slug array contains single value or multple value

Answer (score 0):

Try this aggregate query...

```
db.tests.aggregate([{
        "$unwind": "$slug"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$slug",
            "totalScore": {
                "$sum": "$score"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "@BANANA", 
    "totalScore" : 5.3
}
{ 
    "_id" : "@APPLE", 
    "totalScore" : 17.6
}
```